# mysql select query , trying to select multiple values but the query shows 1 value

Tags: mysql, wordpress, select, join

i have MYSQL database with WORDPRESS that have many tables and trying to do a select query in order to get the requested data.

tables are :

**site_locaion:**

```
siteID(PRIMARY KEY)
locationName
lat
long
```

**employee:**

```
employeeID(PRIMARY KEY)
employeeName
```

**inspection_info:**

```
inspectionID(PRIMARY KEY)
inspectionDate
employeeID
```

**inspection_site:**

```
inspectionID(PRIMARY KEY)

siteID(PRIMARY KEY)
```

i am trying to get the below fields  where the **employeeName** has several values.

## SQL qyery

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("select 
       l.locationName
       , n.inspectionDate
       , e.employeeName
  from army_site_location l
  LEFT  
  JOIN inspection_site s
    on l.siteID = s.siteID
  LEFT
    JOIN inspection_info n
    on n.inspectionID = s.inspectionID
    LEFT
  JOIN employeeName e
    on n.employeeID=e.employeeID
     where 
    l.locationName = %s
    AND 
    e.employeeID = %d
    AND 
    n.inspectionID = %d
   ",$site_name,$soldier_name, $inspection_date);

 $query_submit =$wpdb->get_results($sql, OBJECT);
```

where the result must   **2 employee** in the same date and the same location  but the system just fetch **1 employee**

[image]

Comment: have you tried outer joins? might be some error in the db or ids

Comment: @Xandl i am using outer join  in my query

Comment: without the WHERE, the list is huge richt?

Comment: @Xandl the WHERE is for taking the user input in order to retrieve the requested data .

Comment: yes, i understood that - I just wanted to know what happenes when the query was not filtered.